# How do I find the Activities in a TabActivity?

Tags: android

My application extends TabActivity, which manages the Activities of the application - about 6 of them, which come and go quite dynamically. I set up a 'settings' menu option at the TabActivity level, which, when triggered, needs to visit each Activity and change the setting on each one.

The problem is that I can't find how to get a list of the Activites which are being managed by the TabActivity. Unless I'm missing it, there's nothing in the API which allows me to find those sub-Activities so I can talk to them all.

I can store a static list of Activities and ensure I keep the list up to date, but this seems like something the TabActivity should be doing. Since it apparently isn't, I'm inclined to think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just have a `Set<Activity>` on the Tab activity.
And "addActivity(Activity x)" method on it.

Now when the TabActivity constructs and calls (indirectly) the `onCreate()` of the embedded Activity, this Activity calls `getParent().addActivity(this)` which fills the set on the TabActivity.

For your taks you then just need to loop over the set and call the methods you need.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done. It works. :) It just struck me as odd that the API doesn't make this information available for you. Any idea why not?